# Can't see which of my units I have selected

Tags: starcraft-2

Starcraft 2 just updated itself.
And now I can't see which of my units I have selected.

I can select, say, a Marine, but there is no visible indication that the Marine is selected. Makes it very difficult to see which units I have "grabbed" to command.

I found nothing on the internet about this, and chatted with an opponent just now who said it's working normally for them (no problem).

Any ideas?

This selection circle is missing.

Screenshot of what is MISSING (green circle around the Protoss worker)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll still have to wait for Blizzard to fix it. As of now the bug is still present.

Some blue post trying to help (but that doesn't seem to help everyone):

> Hey all,
>
> Thank you for the reports. We are aware of the green selection circle
>   not showing for some players and are investigating the cause of this.
>   This does look related to the flickering issues we are seeing with AMD
>   crossfire enabled. While we do work on finding a fix for this we do
>   have some workaround you can all try that we have seen help some
>   player.
>
> • Change StarCraft II to fullscreen mode in the StarCraft II graphic
>   settings.
>
> • Reset In-Game Options.
>
> 1. Select the game in the Blizzard app and click Options .
> 2. Click Game Settings.
> 3. Click on Reset In-Game Options.
> 4. Click Done and launch the game normally.
>
> • To be on the safe side make sure Windows and the drivers in the
>   computer are up to date.
>
> • Please lower the graphic setting in Starcraft II to see if there is
>   a difference.
>
> • Disable AMD Crossfire

After this there was no further statement on this issue, so if that doesn't help you'll have to wait.